# Raster crop not wokring

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, crop

After importing a .tiff as rasterLayer, I want to crop it to certain geographical location. I'm using the following piece of code

```
rawData <- raster("myFile.tif")
focusedCoordds <- extent(-116,-70,31,45)
croppedData <- crop(x = rawData, y = focusedCoordds)
```

But the problem I'm facing is that the cropped data doesn't have any variation in the data - meaning, the values that the file is supposed to have after trimming are instead just zeros! Thus, when I do a leaflet plot, I'm just getting one colour - corresponding to zero. Interestingly, when I apply this to other part of the world, it seems to work fine, but not the the coordinates above. Any idea what might be going on?!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Make sure to read [How to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help the community help you. Also, list all the libraries you are using to make clear which functions come from which packages